# Missing (date)column in a jtable imported from mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, date, jtable

all runs corectly except my date column in jtable doesnt fill with data from database mysql. Any mistake figured?

```
public final class ClientiFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {    

    public ClientiFrame() {
        initComponents();
        Show_Clienti_In_JTable();
    }

    //mysql java connectivity
    public Connection getConnection()
    {
       Connection con;

       try {
           con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sys", "student5", "student5");
           return con;
       } 
      catch (SQLException e) {
           return null;
       }
    }

    //creating arrayList(the problem might be here)
    public ArrayList<Client> getClientiList()
    {
       ArrayList<Client> clientiList = new ArrayList<>();
       Connection connection = getConnection();

       String query = "SELECT * FROM  clienti ";
       Statement st;
       ResultSet rs;

       try {
           st = connection.createStatement();
           rs = st.executeQuery(query);
           Client client;
           while(rs.next())
           {
               client = new Client(rs.getInt("id"),rs.getString("nume"),rs.getString("prenume"),rs.getInt("suma"),rs.getDate("data"));
               clientiList.add(client);
           }
       } catch (SQLException e) {
       }
       return clientiList;
    }

    //displaying in jtable(not good)(the problem might be here)
    public void Show_Clienti_In_JTable()
    {
       ArrayList<Client> list = getClientiList();
       DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable_Display_Clienti.getModel();
       Object[] row = new Object[5];
       for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
       {
           row[0]=list.get(i).getId();
           row[1]=list.get(i).getNume();
           row[2]=list.get(i).getPrenume();
           row[3]=list.get(i).getSuma();
           row[4]=list.get(i).getData();
           model.addRow(row);
       }
     }
```

And this is my Client class

```
public class Client {

    private final int id;
    private final String nume;
    private final String prenume;
    private final int suma;
    private final Date data;

    public Client(int Id, String Nume, String Prenume, int Suma, Date Data)
    {
        this.id = Id;
        this.nume = Nume;
        this.prenume = Prenume;
        this.suma = Suma;
        this.data = Data;
    }

    public int getCodcli()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public String getNume()
    {
        return nume;
    }

    public String getPrenume()
    {
        return prenume;
    }

    public int getSuma()
    {
        return suma;
    }
    public Date getData()
    {
        return data;
    }
}
```

My jtable has the date column
also my table from mysql has everything needs
i did the same way i did to the other varibles(id nume etc) and when i tried to simply replace the date with an int or string variable it worked, but i need the date .. if u cant figure it out can someone send me a tutorial at least(how to import a date data from mysql to jtable java. i couldnt find anything on youtube);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It’s pretty much code for a question. You should learn [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Said knowing it’s not something you know how to do from the outset.

Comment: What does the `JTable` show instead of the correct dates from the database? An empty column? When asking for debugging help. always be precise about the difference between expected and observed behaviour.

Comment: The problem may be in getting the data from the database, or in displaying the dates in the `JTable`. Maybe start out by doing those two tasks in two separate programs so you’re sure that works. Next, use a debugger (or `System.out.println`)  to determine how far your dates are correct in the big program.

Comment: Also, the `Date` class you are using is long outmoded. This is not the (sole) reason for your problem, but you should want to look into [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), it is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: When asking us to read and try to understand your code, please follow the Java coding conventions. Method names and parameter names should begin with a lowercase letter and not have underscores in them. Seasoned Java programmers will read your program more easily when you respect this.

Comment: Solved. I tried to make a single date variable and it worked. Then i made a new project and worked..still don't know why but it's done thanks:)

Comment: Congrats, Flavian Bulancea! And please allow me to suggest you delete your question. I won’t be useful for future readers. You’ve got a delete link under the question.